# How to set the horizontal separation of group of rectangles

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows, backgrounds

In the following diagram:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,calc,fit,backgrounds,shapes.multipart,positioning}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle, rounded corners, thick, node 
distance=7em, 
text width=6em, text centered, minimum height=3.5em}}
%\tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -{Latex[length=2mm,width=1mm]}}}
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
%=======================================
% Adjust the boarder of the flowchart
%=======================================
\setlength\PreviewBorder{4pt}%

\begin{document}
%************************************************************
%************************************************************
%  Define block styles
%************************************************************
%************************************************************
\tikzset{
block/.style={rectangle split, draw, rectangle split parts=2,text width=14em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
grnblock/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=green!20, text width=10em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em}, 
whtblock/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=white!20, text width=14em, text centered, minimum height=4em},    
line/.style={draw, {latex[length=3mm,width=2.25mm]}-{latex[length=3mm,width=2.25mm]}},
cloud/.style={draw, ellipse,fill=white!20, node distance=3cm,    minimum height=4em},  
% container/.style={draw, rectangle,dashed,inner sep=0.28cm, rounded corners,fill=yellow!20,minimum height=4cm}}
container1/.style={draw, rectangle,inner sep=0.48cm,fill=blue!10,minimum height=4cm},
container2/.style={draw, rectangle,inner sep=0.28cm,fill=green!10,minimum height=4em}}
%************************************************************
%************************************************************ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.25cm, auto,every text node part/.style={align=center}]
%
%===============================================    
%  Reader
%===============================================  
  \node [whtblock,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] (LBT) {LBT \\[0.5em]Reader Anti-Collision Protocol};   
  \node [whtblock, below=of LBT, node distance=2.5cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] (FSA) {FSA \\[0.5em]Anti-Collision Protocol};
  \node [whtblock, below=of FSA, node distance=2.5cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] (PHY) {PHY Layer};
%*****************
% TAG
%***************
  \node [whtblock, right=of PHY, node distance=13cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] (PHYtag) {PHY Layer\\[0.5em](Energy Harvester)};
  \node [whtblock, above=of PHYtag, node distance=13cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] (FSAtag) {FSA \\[0.5em]Anti-Collision Protocol};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   CONTAINERS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=3mm]LBT.north);
  \node [container1,fit=(aux1) (FSA)(PHY)] (Reader) {};
  \node at (Reader.north) [fill=white,draw,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] {\textbf{Reader}};
%-----------------------------------------------------------
  \coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=3mm]FSAtag.north);
  \node [container1,fit=(aux2) (PHYtag)(FSAtag)] (TAG) {};
  \node at (TAG.north) [fill=white,draw,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] {\textbf{Tag}};
\end{scope}
%************************************************************
%************************************************************
%  Draw edges
%************************************************************
%************************************************************
\draw [line,darkgray,very thick] (LBT.south) -- (FSA.north);
\draw [line,darkgray,very thick] (FSA.south) -- (PHY.north);
\draw [line,darkgray,very thick] (FSAtag.south) -- (PHYtag.north);

\draw [-latex,darkgray,ultra thick] ([yshift=6pt]PHY.east) -- node [above] {Power-Up \\[0.5em] Link} ([yshift=6pt]PHYtag.west);
\draw [-latex,darkgray,ultra thick] ([yshift=-6pt]PHYtag.west) -- node [below] {Backscattered \\[0.5em] Link} ([yshift=-6pt]PHY.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The text of the horizontal arrows between the Reader's and Tag's group of rectangles is overlapped with the box containers.

I would like to separate the two groups (Reader and Tag) to fit the text of the arrows in the blank space between the two groups.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit after @marmot's useful comment about the non used `node distance` inside the nodes (since `right=<Some Length> of <Poin>` doesn't allow the `node distance` to really be used):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,calc,fit,backgrounds,shapes.multipart,positioning}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle, rounded corners, thick, node 
distance=7em, 
text width=6em, text centered, minimum height=3.5em}}
%\tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -{Latex[length=2mm,width=1mm]}}}
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
%=======================================
% Adjust the boarder of the flowchart
%=======================================
\setlength\PreviewBorder{4pt}%

\begin{document}
%************************************************************
%************************************************************
%  Define block styles
%************************************************************
%************************************************************
\tikzset{
block/.style={rectangle split, draw, rectangle split parts=2,text width=14em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
grnblock/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=green!20, text width=10em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em}, 
whtblock/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=white!20, text width=14em, text centered, minimum height=4em},    
line/.style={draw, {latex[length=3mm,width=2.25mm]}-{latex[length=3mm,width=2.25mm]}},
cloud/.style={draw, ellipse,fill=white!20, node distance=3cm,    minimum height=4em},  
% container/.style={draw, rectangle,dashed,inner sep=0.28cm, rounded corners,fill=yellow!20,minimum height=4cm}}
container1/.style={draw, rectangle,inner sep=0.48cm,fill=blue!10,minimum height=4cm},
container2/.style={draw, rectangle,inner sep=0.28cm,fill=green!10,minimum height=4em}}
%************************************************************
%************************************************************ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.25cm, auto,every text node part/.style={align=center}]
%
%===============================================    
%  Reader
%===============================================  
  \node [whtblock,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] (LBT) {LBT \\[0.5em]Reader Anti-Collision Protocol};   
  \node [whtblock, below=of LBT,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] (FSA) {FSA \\[0.5em]Anti-Collision Protocol};
  \node [whtblock, below=of FSA,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] (PHY) {PHY Layer};
%*****************
% TAG
%***************
  \node [whtblock, right=of PHY,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,shift={(3cm,0)}] (PHYtag) {PHY Layer\\[0.5em](Energy Harvester)};
  \node [whtblock, above=of PHYtag,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] (FSAtag) {FSA \\[0.5em]Anti-Collision Protocol};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   CONTAINERS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=3mm]LBT.north);
  \node [container1,fit=(aux1) (FSA)(PHY)] (Reader) {};
  \node at (Reader.north) [fill=white,draw,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] {\textbf{Reader}};
%-----------------------------------------------------------
  \coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=3mm]FSAtag.north);
  \node [container1,fit=(aux2) (PHYtag)(FSAtag)] (TAG) {};
  \node at (TAG.north) [fill=white,draw,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] {\textbf{Tag}};
\end{scope}
\node[whtblock,shift={(0,7.6cm)},minimum width=18cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] at ($(Reader)!.5!(TAG)$) {\textbf{Scenario Setup}};
%************************************************************
%************************************************************
%  Draw edges
%************************************************************
%************************************************************
\draw [line,darkgray,very thick] (LBT.south) -- (FSA.north);
\draw [line,darkgray,very thick] (FSA.south) -- (PHY.north);
\draw [line,darkgray,very thick] (FSAtag.south) -- (PHYtag.north);

\draw [-latex,darkgray,ultra thick] ([yshift=6pt]PHY.east) -- node [above] {Power-Up \\[0.5em] Link} ([yshift=6pt]PHYtag.west);
\draw [-latex,darkgray,ultra thick] ([yshift=-6pt]PHYtag.west) -- node [below] {Backscattered \\[0.5em] Link} ([yshift=-6pt]PHY.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Except of the change that @marmot asked (in case a future user will find this answer and suppose that these commands could be combined as provided in my previous version and take effect), I just added:

1) a `shift={(<Some Length For X>,<Some Length For Y>)}` for the shift needed in the initial question, and

2) a new `node` command for the "title box" as requested in the comments

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to ask how to draw a node rectangle with the text "scenario setup" and place it covering both groups, Reader and Tag boxes, at the top of the diagram. Can you tell me how to set the width a rectangle node to the distance between the left side of the Reader's boxes and the right side of the Tag's boxes?.

Comment: if I set a new node, `\node [whtblock, above=of Reader, node distance=13cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,minimum height=3em, minimum width=23em] (SCN) {Scenario Setup};` the box is centered in the reader container group and if I increase the width the box expands at both sides. I would like this new box limited to reader and the tag containers.

Comment: See edit... You were close

Comment: Welcome... I am not sure that this was what you was looking for, but by changing the distances you can have it I suppose. Good night