# How to add line connecting two coordinates on a graph with logarithmic x-axis scale?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to add the line going through the points (1000,-8.5) and (10000,-27.79). This is the latex I have so far.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
    xlabel={Frequency (Hz)},
    ylabel={Gain (db)},
    xmin=0, xmax=20000,
    ymin=-30, ymax=10,
    xtick={0,100,1000,10000},
    ytick={10,0,-10,-20,-30},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    only marks,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (100,-0.18)(1000,-8.5)(2000,-14.15)(4000,-19.83)(10000,-27.79)
    };

% add plot of equation going through points (1000,-8.5) and (10000,-27.79) here

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

All the equations passing through those two points don't show up correctly on the plot, I'm guessing because the logarithmic scale. I have tried 49.37-19.29*x but that doesn't work. That equation is reached by applying log(x) before calculating the line connecting the two points. How do I get a line passing through those points?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `\addplot[no marks] coordinates {(1000,-8.5) (10000,-27.79)};` ?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
    xlabel={Frequency (Hz)},
    ylabel={Gain (db)},
    xmin=0, xmax=20000,
    ymin=-30, ymax=10,
    xtick={0,100,1000,10000},
    ytick={10,0,-10,-20,-30},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    legend pos=north east
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    only marks,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (100,-0.18)(1000,-8.5)(2000,-14.15)(4000,-19.83)(10000,-27.79)
    };
\addlegendentry{data}

\addplot[color=orange,no marks] coordinates {(1000,-8.5) (10000,-27.79)};
\addlegendentry{fit}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think (s)he wants the equation in the legend. (Already provided in his question I think -but didn't solved- See his comment on my deleted answer)

Comment: @koleygr Thanks! One can replace `\addlegendentry{fit}` by `\addlegendentry{$E=mc^2$}`, say, to get an equation. Please consider changing your answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/477600/121799. You need only something like `\node [whtblock, right=3cm of PHY,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont].` In your answer, all the `node distance` keys have no effect because they are to be placed earlier. That is, remove all `node distance` statements and put the distance in the `below of` and so on keys.

Comment: Ok fixed... Didn't realized what you said at first time and thought that I have to study things to make the requested edit and know what I am doing. But what you said was simple and thus, edited the question. thanks